# while loop optimization a little bit

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, micro-optimization

I've got a `while` loop running that grabs all the posts on my site

`while ( $all_query->have_posts() ) : $all_query->the_post();`

there is meta data in each on that I need to play with. It's a field called `'rate'` and I need to merge like values, 1-5.

Currently, I've got this

```
while ( $all_query->have_posts() ) : $all_query->the_post();
    $fives = 0;
    $fours = 0;
    $threes = 0;
    $twos = 0;
    $ones = 0;
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rate', true) == 'five') { 
        $fives = $fives + 5;
    }
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rate', true) == 'four') { 
        $fours = $fours + 4;
    }
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rate', true) == 'three') { 
        $threes = $threes + 3;
    }
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rate', true) == 'two') { 
        $twos = $twos + 2;
    }
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rate', true) == 'one') { 
        $ones = $ones + 1;
    }
    endwhile;
```

it works, but it's really gross.

Is there a more optimized and clean way to do something like this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `switch`.

Comment: Are you trying to average the rate?

Comment: @Supericy - essentially, yes. I used to do 5 separate loops, but that was getting very expensive. So i'm trying to condense it all into 1 loop and manipulating variables from the one to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit of array manipulation can greatly simplify this:

```
$counts = array_fill(1, 5, 0);
$labels = array(1 => 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');

while(...) {
    $index = array_search(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rate', true), $labels);
    $counts[$index] += $index;
}
```

The totals are kept inside `$counts`, with `$counts[1]` being the total of ones. `$labels` is there to help match the textual representation with the array positions inside `$counts` -- this could of course be done with a plain `switch` instead.

The loop uses `array_search` to convert textual representations to array indexes, then simply increments the corresponding count by an amount equal to the index.

Production code should of course also account for the possibility of `array_search` returning `false`.

Comment: Aha! My good sir, you're absolutely wonderful. This works beautifully! With a little tweaking it works **brilliantly** and is MUCH cleaner than what I had before! Thanks!! :)